# Java hibernate: How to set column varchar to max?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have column `String post`.

I want map this `post` like a string.

I am using:

```
@Column(updatable = true, name = "Post", nullable = false, length=50)
    public String getPost() {
        return post;
    }
```

This code mapping `varchar(50)`.

How can I mapp `varchar(max)`.

I try this code. But I can't compile it.

```
@Column(updatable = true, name = "Post", nullable = false, length=max)
    public String getPost() {
        return post;
    }
```

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done using code below:

```
@Column(updatable = true, name="Post", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar(max)")
private String post;
```

Haven't tried this but it should work based on this [columnDefinition](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition()).

#### UPD #1

Basically you could add annotation `@Lob` OR use very large value for `length` in `@Column`.

From [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html):

> `@Lob` indicates that the property should be persisted in a Blob or a Clob depending on the property type: `java.sql.Clob`, `Character[]`, `char[]` and `java.lang.String` will be persisted in a Clob. `java.sql.Blob`, `Byte[]`, `byte[]` and serializable type will be persisted in a Blob.

Comment: I try your code, but this code not map my table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write like this:

```
 @Column(updatable = true,name="Post",nullable = false,columnDefinition = "varchar(255)")
 public String getPost() {
    return post;
}
```

For more info go to [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html)

Comment: I don't think that 50 is max.